# ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Wrong or unknown protocol: SELECT

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysql2, actionview

I get this weird error in my rails application

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 176742ms (ActiveRecord: 148.5ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Wrong or unknown protocol: SELECT  `lines`.* FROM `lines` WHERE `lines`.`id` = 15 LIMIT 1):
    22:               <% if defined?(Haml) && respond_to?(:block_is_haml?) && block_is_haml?(block) %>
    23:                 <% capture_haml(day, sorted_events.fetch(day, []), &block) %>
    24:               <% else %>
    25:                 <% block.call day, sorted_events.fetch(day, []) %>
    26:               <% end %>
    27:             <% end %>
    28:           <% end %>

app/views/presences/index.html.erb:47:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_presences_index_html_erb__679688437_89682920'
app/views/presences/index.html.erb:7:in `each'
app/views/presences/index.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_presences_index_html_erb__679688437_89682920'
app/views/presences/index.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_presences_index_html_erb__679688437_89682920'
```

app/views/presences/index.html.erb:47:

```
<th style="background: greenyellow"><%= Line.find(l).name + " bla: " + tmp.size.to_s %></th>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this one or has an idea why the mysql error appears? In my code in front I do a few select and detect statements on arrays. There are not many mysql queries... And this error just happens in my test environment (copy of production environment on different VM). On my dev environment everything works like a charm.

Comment: looks like you do not have a "lines" table. Goto rails console and make sure it.

Comment: It is there. I can access it in any other view as well. the SQL query shown above works in my SQL console as well

Comment: Maybe in `Line.find(l)` the `l` is missing, interesting case never seen this ?

Comment: I access the `l` in a view lines before already with the same code just in another case and it works. If not it would throw an error at line `app/views/presences/index.html.erb:17` 
I refactored the code to clean up a n+1 problem and since then it fails to run with the strange mysql error

Comment: I was able to refactor the code in a different way to avoid the problem. But now I have in my (rufus-)scheduler the same issue. When the application starts the first run works as intended, the second fails with __size: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `exports` WHERE `exports`.`date` = '2020-02-11' config/initializers/scheduler.rb:21
Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Wrong or unknown protocol: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `exports` WHERE `exports`.`date` = '2020-02-11'
D:/RubyonRails/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/client.rb:131:in `_query'__ Is concurrency maybe an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with reinstalling the MySQL server on the current version with a new config. Somehow there were no code changes needed...